# conditional statement not working as expected in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a method which takes 2-arguments - message to print on the screen and (default) value. If the default value is `nil` then I want just the message to be printed on the screen otherwise message should contain the default value in square brackets.

For example: If I pass `method1("Hello" , "")`, it should print `Hello` but if I pass `method1("Hello", "User")`, it should print `Hello [User]:`. But right now it printing only `Hello` even in second scenario.

Below is the piece of my code:

```
def method1(mes, value)
  val = ""
  begin
    if value == "" || "#{value}".to_i == 0
      val = ask(mes) do |ch|
        ch = true
      end
    else
      val = ask(message+" [#{value}]: ") do |ch|
        ch = true
      end
    end

    if val == "" then
      val = "#{value}"
    end

  rescue => e
    print "Except occured in method1(#{mes}, #{value}) "+e
  end

  return val
end
```

Comment: Things like `"#{value}".to_i` are usually pointless, as `value.to_i` would do the job here.

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`to_i`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/to_i) returns `0` for every string which is not a number:

```
"User".to_i == 0
# => true
```

So, in your code:

```
value = "User"

if value == "" || "#{value}".to_i == 0
  puts "was here"
end
# => "was here"
```

You should change your condition, perhaps to check if `value` is `nil` or empty:

```
if value.nil? || value.empty?
```

If you are using Rails, you can use the [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) method:

```
if value.blank?
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. But trying `if value.nil? || value.empty?` is failing for numbers. How can I make it work for numbers?

Comment: @itsh you can use value.nil? || value == ""

Comment: I converted `value` to string using `value.to_s` and then compared it with `0`. It worked. Here is my working conditional statement `if value.empty? || value == "0"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rails

```
value.blank?
```

If you are using only ruby

```
empty = input2.respond_to?(:empty?) ? input2.empty? : input2.to_s.length.zero?
```

as value.empty? will not work on numbers

Complete solution

```
def method1(input1, input2)
  result = input2.respond_to?(:empty?) ? !input2.empty? : input2.to_s.length > 0
  input2 = "#{ result ? input2 : '' }"
  puts input2.empty? ? input1 : "#{ input1 } [#{ input2 }]" 
end

method1('Hello', '')
method1('Hello', 2)
method1('Hello', [])
method1('Hello', [2])
method1('Hello', {})
method1('Hello', { a: 2 })
method1('Hello', false)

#Output
Hello
Hello [Mr]
Hello [2]
Hello
Hello [[2]]
Hello
Hello [{:a=>2}]
Hello [false]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def func(mes, val = "")
  puts val.size != 0  ? "#{mes} [#{val}]" : "#{mes}"
end
```

Outputs:

```
func(123)             # 123
func("Hello")         # Hello
func("Hello", 123)    # Hello [123]
func("Hello", "test") # Hello [test]
```